# Dealing with out of hours emails?

Tags: management, work-life-balance, work-time, phone, after-hours

I am a eCommerce development manager for a successful business. We are a small team but work very much as such with everyone fully committed to the cause. When I first started I was told that I shouldn't access my work email on a personal device. That said, because of the nature of work I read it anyway and nothing has been said not to do so. On the odd occasion my boss will email out of hours to look into an issue. Normally it can picked up the next day but there have been times when I had to deal with it immediately. Case in point this weekend I my boss emailed me with an immediate request. If it wasn't for me reading my email on my personal phone this would have gone unanswered.

To be clear, I really don't mind dealing with the emails out of hours and I really don't want a company phone as I already have my own and don't want to carry two around with me.

Do I say nothing and just carry on or do I say something? If so what would be the best approach? I suppose what I am after is some sort of recognition but is that ok?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. If you don't want to have to carry around two phones, maybe it would be best if you kept your mouth shut?

Comment: If your work emails get stored on your own phone, there may be data-management issues where all copies of an email cannot be found if they need to be. Which may be why you were told not to access work email on non-work devices.

Comment: "Case in point this weekend I my boss emailed me with an immediate request."  Did your boss tell you not to access work email on your personal device?  If so, how did he expect you to immediately address his email?

Comment: I am surprised at the responses this has generated. On the one hand, its been down voted 4 times but on the other I have four useful comments with their own up votes.

Comment: Regarding votes: The first and third comments are requesting clarification. It would probably help to answer those questions. I'm also not not sure what you mean by "recognition". Do you mean you want credit for working outside of work hours or confirmation that your boss knows you're using your personal device?

Answer (score 8):

> Do I say nothing and just carry on or do I say something?

You can just ignore the mail as if you never saw it. My policy is to do just that, if it's really urgent they can ring me and ask me to check my email.

This makes them initiate the discussion on expectations regarding emails, rather than me, and avoids any potential conflict or misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

In some countries, the law states you don't read work emails outside of work time.

This is to stop employers taking unpaid free time as work time for free.

If you wish to be available 24/7/365 then that will be your choice.

Many people who have to do unsociable hours callouts etc get paid a premium for being on call or paid for the time at a rate above the normal daily rate for dealing with issues "out of hours".

Sort it out with your boss, but will you stop work out of hours or work for free if he says he won't pay?

Comment: In Ireland there is legislation in progress about being contacted out of hours. Im not looking for payment, not unless takes a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

I don't read works emails out of hours. That's it.

My boss has my private mobile phone number, so he can call me at any time if there is an emergency. As did my previous boss. And the company before, someone in HR did. So they can get me in an emergency. Fortunately each of them knew what is and what isn't an emergency. Haven't had one so far.

Email is totally inappropriate to get your attention out of hours. (But of course someone can send an email and then call you to check your email).

Work should be done in your work hours if at all possible. Had to work at midnight once because of a bug that happened exactly at midnight (caused by the date change) and had to be caught at that time :-(

Answer (score 0):

Communication is a very big issue, and one of the things it feels like your company lacks is a defined protocol for identifying which communication vector to use and when. I would recommend setting up a formal protocol to define exactly that in the form of:

- Email is used for formal communication. Response time is expected to
  be > 1 day.
- Chat communication tool is used for informal direct
  communication. Response time is expected to be < 2 hours.
- Text is used for direct communication of importance. Response time is
  expected to be < 1 hour.
- Phone/voice mail is used for direct communication of critical need. Response time is expected to be < 15
  minutes.

This is just a general idea for it. You may not even have an internal chat communication tool. The core of it is assigning a well-defined and published protocol for understanding how to communicate based on the priority of need. It might even be useful to include something to indicate email is not to be used on weekends as a priority communication tool.